# Enviando un json por Ajax y el controlador lo recibe todos los datos en nulo?

Tags: c#, jquery, mvc

Envió unas tabla de inputs con el siguiente código:

```
        $('#guardar').click(function(){
            var header = $('table thead tr th').map(function () {
                return $(this).text().trim();
            });

            var Datos = $('table tbody tr').map(function (i) {
                var row = {};
                $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
                    var rowName = header[i];
                    row[rowName] = $(this).find('input').val();
                });
                return row;
            }).get();

            $.ajax({                  
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Guardar", "Inicio")',
                data: JSON.stringify({Datos}),
                dataType: JSON,
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert("Error del servidor");
                }
            });
        });
```

y lo recibo con el controlador:

```
    public JsonResult Guardar(List<Temp> Datos)
    {
       object ver = Datos;

        return Json(Datos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

y tengo la clase:

```
    public class Temp
    {
        public String Albaran;
        public String Cp;
        public String Destinatario;
        public String Direccion;
        public String Fecha;
        public String Observaciones;
        public String Poblacion;
        public String Provincia;
        public String Telefono;

    }
```

Captura del json en el console.log:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El hecho es que recibo todas las 20 filas en el jsonresult que tengo pero todos su valores en null.

**Solcionado**

tengo que agregar el {get;set} a las variable de la clase Temp

Comment: Puedes pegar aquí el json que se genera y se envía? Y de paso puedes probar usando [FromBody] en tu método guardar public JsonResult Guardar([FromBody] List<Temp> Datos)

Comment: Ya subi la imagen del json, no me funciona el fronbody @MiguelFebres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema consistía en que tengo que agregar el `{ get; set; }` a las variable de la clase `Temp`.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas.

Lo más fácil es que primero intentes enviar un objeto de forma "manual".
No intentes cargar el objeto desde el formulario para hacer el test.

```
var Datos = {'Albaran': 'datos', ...};
```

En caso de que funcionase, comprueba que el objeto que se está mandando es correcto desde la terminal de JavaScript (F12), simplemente con un:
console.log(Datos);

justo antes de tu llamada al Ajax, para ver que el objeto es correcto.  (Se que has pegado una imágen, pero me da error 503 al intentar cargarla).

También comentarte que no hace falta que pases a string el objeto. Es posible que el navegador o la aplicación esté cogiendo el post directamente como un texto y no como el objeto que quieras enviar.

También puede ser más fácil la solución de, esa tabla con inputs, meterla dentro de un formulario con un ID, y obtener un objeto directamente con:

```
var Datos = $('#idFormulario').serializeArray();
```

Coge el atributo "name" como clave, y el valor del campo como valor.

Si esto no te funciona, copia un ejemplo de la tabla en html para que podamos hacer mejores pruebas.